# ChartKick Rails 2 - Google Charts Not Installing

Tags: google-visualization, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm trying to use Chartkick but keep receiving the same error.

`"Error Loading Chart: Please install Google Charts or Highcharts"`

I am trying to use Google Charts and use the javascript_include_tag at the top of my page where I want the chart like this:

`<%= javascript_include_tag "http://www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>`

Not sure why I'm receiving this error and below is also my code requesting the line chart:

`<% @station_names = RegAttendee.find(:all, :select => "distinct(check_in_station)", :conditions => {:show_id => 76 }) %>`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Solved: I added:

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

to the top of my page instead of the ruby javascript_include tag. 

The ruby tag was adding a ".js" to the end of the src url

Comment: Thanks for the follow up post - added it to the readme https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#for-rails-23-and-30